# Read information from FLV file in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv, fancyupload

im just new in AS3 so i have a question hope you guy can help!

I am now using FancyUpload to make an upload tool for my website, for the video module, so user can upload their video in FLV format with limited size and time

With the limited size i can handle it, but with the time ... :(
I dont know how to know the total length of FLV file
Hope you guys can help, and sry 4 my E lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duration of the FLV is contained in the metadata property, check the docs for more info on how to retrieve this data.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#metadata

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onMetaData

Comment: Thanks so much, i've just look out the doc but so sry, im just new in AS3, how to use NetStream to play a FileReference?

Comment: Sorry, totally misunderstood your question! The FileReference will give you the size of the file but won't give you the length or duration of the video. It may be possible to work out an average time by looking at the file size , but they are so many factors that can affect the duration of the video that it may be impossible to be accurate.

Comment: Sorry not reply you soon, i mean how to read the meta data from flv file while i using browse to select the file i want, after browse i have a list of FileReference and i want to check every single file and read itself metadata, can you help give me some code plzzzz?

Comment: Well, this won't be possible I'm afraid. You need to actually load the flv and listen to a metadata event in order to get the duration of the file. Just browsing wont do!

Comment: Is there anyway to do it? like get the full path of that file and read it?

Comment: what do you mean? afaik the only way is to actually load the file

Comment: hmmm, so that's impossible? i just want to validate the flv file after allow it to upload to the server, lol, okey, thanks so much for helping me Mr.PatrickS, really appreciate ^^!

Comment: you're welcome!...  you can always validate the size :) now, if you want to limit the duration, you could stop the file playing after the time limit has been reached...

Answer (score 0):

Although a correct 'flv' file 'should' contain correct length in the metadata tag. But, I have found that it's more error-resilient to get time-stamp from the flv file itself.

Check out the flv spec at http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf. If it's just a the *.flv file that you are worried about that then Annex-E is all you need to look in this spec.
Basically, the last 4 bytes would tell you the length of last tag in the flv file. So read the last tag in the file and then get the timestamp of that tag. This should be a tell you the length of the video.

Moreover, I assume you are trying to these check at client side itself. So, I'd say that put the check on size before loading the file to read/parse it.